# Union of uncountable set with cardinality c with a countable set

Tags: functions, set-theory, infinity

Let $A$ be an uncountable set with cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ (so it is in bijection with the power set of $\mathbb{N}$) and let $B$ be a countable set (finite or infinite). Intuitively I want to say that the union of $A$ and $B$ has cardinality $\mathfrak{c}$ as well, however I cannot find a way to prove this. How could one go about proving that $|A\cup B| = \mathfrak{c}$?

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135221/real-analysis-countable-and-uncountable-set) might help. As a rough hint, how are subsets of $\Bbb N$ related to $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb {N})$? As an aside, `\mathfrak{c}`, which gives us $\mathfrak{c}$, is the appropriate markup

Comment: Probably already answered at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3999807/cardinality-does-not-change-when-substracting-a-countable-subset-from-an-uncount or at one of the questions linked there.

Comment: For cardinal arithmetic, $\kappa+\lambda=\max(\kappa,\lambda)$.  Part of this is just noting that $\kappa+\kappa=\kappa$.  So if $\kappa<\lambda$, take the copy of $\kappa$ inside $\lambda=\kappa\mathrel{+}$ (the rest), and code two copies of $\kappa$ into it.  Then $\lambda$ can be viewed as just $\kappa+\kappa\mathrel{+}$ (the rest), which is thus $\kappa+\lambda$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A$ is of size continuum. Then there is a bijection $f\colon A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let $A_0 = f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$, a countable subset of $A$. Notice that f restricted to $A \!\setminus\! A_0$ is a bijection between that set and $\mathbb{R} \!\setminus\! \mathbb{N}$, and $f$ restricted to $A_0$ bijects it with $\mathbb{N}$.

Now suppose $B$ is countable and disjoint from $A$. Then $A_0 \cup B$ is countable, and you can use $f$ to define a new bijection $g\colon A_0 \cup B \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$. The definition of $g$ depends on whether $B$ is finite or infinite, but the result in both cases is the same:
the union of g with $f \!\restriction\! (A\!\setminus\! A_0)$ is a bijection from $A \cup B = (A\!\setminus\! A_0) \cup A_0 \cup B$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Can you fill in the details of how to define $g$?